# How to count specific neighbours in a nested list in Python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a problem where I need create a function to solve the number of N's(ninjas) in a nested list of given coordinates x, y:

```
ninjas = [['N', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', ' '],
         ['N', ' ', 'N', ' ', ' '],
         ['N', 'N', 'N', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

So, if my coordinates are x=1 and y=2, the function should return 8 (the number of ninjas surrounding the coordinate). I've battled with this problem for 48 straight hours and I can't get my head around this. The solution should not contain any fancy numpy.imports. Only basic for-loops and...

How should I proceed with this problem? Any hints?

Comment: Help us answer your question by providing the code you've written so far - thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I haven't gotten anything done yet about this function. Just can't seem to get my head around it. All I have written is a function which ask's the user for x and y coordinates, and also checks that they arent out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WAY** over the `PEP-8` `79` characters per `line` limit, but here's my `one-line` solution:

```
def surrounding(ninjas, x, y):
   return [ninjas[r][c] for r in range(y-1 if y > 0 else y, y + 2 if y < len(ninjas)-1 else y + 1) for c in range(x-1 if x > 0 else x, x + 2 if x < len(ninjas[0])-1 else x + 1)].count('N')
```

which works as expected:

```
surrounding(ninjas, 1, 2)
```

which gives `8`.

```
surrounding(ninjas, 4, 5)
```

which gives `0`.

---

If you want to break it down into something a little more *readable*, then here is a more sensible `function` to do the job:

```
def surrounding(ninjas, x, y):
   neighbours = []
   for r in range(y-1 if y > 0 else y, y+2 if y < len(ninjas)-1 else y+1):
      for c in range(x-1 if x > 0 else x, x+2 if x < len(ninjas[0])-1 else x+1):
         neighbours.append(ninjas[r][c])
   return neighbours.count('N')
```

---

*Note that both these solutions rely on the `ninjas` `list` being `rectangular`*

---

**How they work**

Both `functions` work in the same way, just one is crammed into a `list-comprehension` and the other `appends` to a `list` of `neighbours`.

The steps for calculating the surrounding Ninjas is as follows:

1. Initialise a `list` to store the `cell` values/
2. Loop through the `rows` in the `2d-list` from `1` above if there are no walls above else from the entered position to `1` below if there are ...
3. Loop through the `columns` inside the current `row` from `1` to the left if there are no walls else from the entered...
4. Add that `cell` to the `neighbours` `list`
5. Return how many Ninjas are in the `neighbours` `list` using `.count('N')`

---

One more thing to note is that this problem could be approached in a slightly different way. Instead of adding *every* `cell` to a `list` and counting the Ninjas in that `list`, we could instead add `1` to a variable  if that `cell` is a Ninja.

The code for that would look like:

```
def surrounding(ninjas, x, y):
   noNinjas = 0
   for r in range(y - 1 if y > 0 else y, y + 2 if y < len(ninjas) else y + 1):
      for c in range(x - 1 if x > 0 else x, x + 2 if x < len(ninjas) else x + 1):
         if ninjas[r][c] == 'N':
            noNinjas += 1
   return noNinjas
```

Comment: This seems to be working, thank you very much for your input. Could you elaborate a bit more what is happening here?

Comment: @teepa Just have, didn't even see your comment, was already typing it!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and explaining this to me step by step.

Comment: @teepa No problemo, please up-vote if you haven't already (I can't tell as they are annonymous)

Comment: I'm actually getting an IndexError if x >= 4 or y >=5. So for example, if I input coordinates 4,1 I get IndexError for neighbours.append(ninjas[r][c])

Comment: @teepa Sorry about that, I have updated the answer to work properly now. The problem was that the check to see if the `cell` was on the `edge` was `1` off what it should have been so it was checking `1` over the `edge` giving an `IndexError` when trying to find the `surrounding` out of the `grid`. Hopefully it works for you to now!

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out before you answered back to me. Anyways, Huge thanks to you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As you can get the (`x`, `y`) element by `ninjas[y][x]`, you can simply check all 8 surrounding elements for an `'N'`:

```
Ns = 0  # Number of 'N's
if ninjas[y + 1][x] == 'N':  # Below
    Ns += 1
if ninjas[y][x + 1] == 'N':  # To the right
    Ns += 1
if ninjas[y - 1][x - 1] == 'N':  # Above to the left
    Ns += 1
...
```

This can of course be written more cleverly by utilizing loops rather than writing out all 8 cases by hand. Also, no bounds checking is performed, meaning that you probably should ensure that (`x`, `y`) is not on the boundary of your 2D data array.

## Edit: Loops

As we need `x -1`, `x` and `x + 1` (and similar for `y`) we can make the loops like so:

```
Ns = 0
for i in range(-1, 2):
    for j in range(-1, 2):
        if i == j == 0:
            # This is just the (x, y) element itself. Skip it
            continue
        if ninjas[y + i][x + j] == 'N':
            Ns += 1
```

Comment: with a check that `x + 1`, `x - 1`, `y + 1`, `y - 1` are in respective range.

Comment: Thank you for your output. Could you elaborate on how should I create those loops?